# Unable to get height of node

Tags: javascript

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/fy7f9gxt/1/)

```
        window.addEventListener("resize", getSize);

          function getSize(){
              var node = document.getElementById('sample');
              var height = node.style.height;
              console.log('height: ', height);//expect 100px, get nothing
          }

    #sample {
     padding: 20px;
     height: 100px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     border: solid blue;
     margin: 10px 300px 10px 25px;
     position: 'relative'

}
```

`node.style.height` is always empty/null.  Note that I set the height to 100px.  Why?  How can I get the css height of the node?

Comment: Use `node.offsetHeight`.

Comment: Or node.clientHeight

Comment: Note you still need to use `node.style.height = '1000px';` for setting values.  Setting `offsetHeight` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `clientHeight` which is going to compute `CSS height + CSS padding`

[Client Height JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rdy9syw8/)

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)

Answer (score 1):

To get the height (without margins) of an element use `element.offsetHeight`.

To access CSS properties directly you have to use `getComputedStyle`:

```
const node = document.getElementById('lorem');
const styles = getComputedStyle(node);
const height = styles.height;
```